# my android application doesnt run?

Tags: android, debugging

I was trying to make application, it was working but now when I run it in emulator it's not even giving me the welcome screen. Code:

```
public class TestArabActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

TextView tvTop,tvBottom; 
TableLayout tlStart;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.welcome_screen);

    //init variables
    initVars();
}

private void initVars(){
    tvTop = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_start_TopTittle);
    tvBottom = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_strat_BottomTittle);
    tlStart = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tl_start);
}
}
```

I used debugger and saw these:

- the value of `savedInstanceState` = null
- values of `tvTop`, `tvBottom` and `tlStart` are null also

Why those values are null? I know this is the problem.

Anyone know how to solve it? Thanks.

Comment: can you post all code also with manifest file and where are you using  tvTop ,tvBottom and tlStart ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use DDMS to debug your application,if it throws any exception, you can see from the stack trace where the problem comes from. if it does not throw any exception. then probably you forgot to declear intent-filter in the menifest:

```
<activity android:name="TestArabActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```